# Añadir informacion a un JSON

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un pequeño juego y quiero guardar las puntuaciones en un json en el localstorage, pero no termino de conseguir manejar bien la informacion.

Mi código es este:

```js
    let local = {
        player: name,
        score: score,
        date: fechaYHora
    };

    let obj = JSON.stringify(local);
    let json = localStorage.getItem("score");
    let final = obj +','+json;
    console.log(final);
    localStorage.setItem('score', '['+final+']');
    console.log(JSON.parse('['+final+']'));
```

Mi objetivo es guardar la información del objeto "local" al principio de lo que exista en la variable "json", que obtengo del localstorage, para asi guardarlo de nuevo con la nueva información.

Al utilizar mi código también me sale al final un elemento null que no termino de averiguar de donde viene.
Lo que me acaba generando es:

`[{"player":"nbttii","score":2,"date":"8/5/2022 20:1:56"},{"player":"nbtt","score":1,"date":"8/5/2022 20:1:28"},{"player":"nb","score":1,"date":"8/5/2022 20:1:21"},null]`

He apañado este código que parece funcionar bien pero creo que tiene que haber una mejor manera de hacerlo, ¿algun consejo?¿como puedo quitar el null?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Porqué trabajar con cadenas cuando puedes trabajar directamente con el Array que tienes en el localstorage? Basta con obtener el valor desde localstorage tal como lo haces: `const arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score"));`, luego simplemente haces un `arr.push(local);` y ya tendrás el Array listo para almacenar en el localstorage: `localStorage.setItem("score", JSON.stringify(arr));`

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estaba haciendo mucho mas complicado de lo que era. Gracias por la ayuda